# Where to put the files of package 'karnaugh-map' when installed manually?

Tags: packages, miktex, updating, karnaugh

I have just installed the package 'karnaugh-map' with the commands:

```
pdflatex karnaugh-map.ins
pdflatex karnaugh-map.dtx
```

Now, I have a installation directory

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\karnaugh-map
```

with the following files:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\karnaugh-map

17/07/2017  11.07    <DIR>          .
17/07/2017  11.07    <DIR>          ..
17/07/2017  10.55             1.198 karnaugh-map.aux
20/02/2017  17.59            60.904 karnaugh-map.dtx
17/07/2017  10.55               162 karnaugh-map.glo
17/07/2017  10.55               638 karnaugh-map.idx
25/11/2016  16.25               683 karnaugh-map.ins
17/07/2017  10.55            40.722 karnaugh-map.log
17/07/2017  10.55               297 karnaugh-map.out
17/07/2017  10.55           252.816 karnaugh-map.pdf
17/07/2017  10.51            33.366 karnaugh-map.sty
17/07/2017  10.55               410 karnaugh-map.toc
20/02/2017  18.16             1.369 README.md
          11 File        392.565 byte
```

The question is: *where I have to put this files?
I use MikTeX and work in Windows 10 environment.*

Thank's to all!

Comment: Why not installing it with MiKTeX’s methods?

Comment: Yes, I have done it. but now TeXstudio say me: Impossible find the input point miktex_utf8_open in the library of dynamic link C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\mixtek\bin\x64\MiKTeX209-popt.dll.

Comment: Such an error means that something is really broken in miktex. So you should correct this error. It sounds as if some packages/dll's are not up-to-date. Run an update (admin) and also check with the package manager admin if there are uninstalled packages starting with miktex (synchronize first) and install them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use MiKTeX’s own method for installing packages.<sup>1</sup> Anyway, here’s what I get on a TeX Live distribution; apart from the starting point (here `texmf-dist`), the rest should be the same on MiKTeX:

```
Included files, by type:
run files:
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.sty
source files:
  texmf-dist/source/latex/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.dtx
  texmf-dist/source/latex/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.ins
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/karnaugh-map/README.md details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf details="Package documentation"
```

Don't forget to update the filename database (FNDB).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The usual method when some Windows application is not working seems to be *reinstalling*.</sup>

Comment: I *never* did reinstall a miktex installation ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Neither did I. `;-P`

Comment: Emm... about solving the issue of "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\mixtek\bin\x64\MiKTeX209-popt.dll" I have reinstalling MiKTeX, GSview, Ghostscript, TeXstudio and LT.
And now all work fine. ;-)